# PHP Fetch Data From Database

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I'm trying to fetch data from hashtag where is #a2 or #ar hashtag but not work with my code

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hashtag=#a2");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  this,

```
$data = "#a2";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hashtag LIKE '%$data%'");
```

Comment: You forgot to remove `=` after hashtag

Comment: should be `$data=addslashes("#a2");`

Comment: If someone sees `$data="#a2"` and replaces it with `$data="#$_GET['tag']"`  you get sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hashtag LIKE '%#a2%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using your method but you just have to enclose `#a2` in quotes like

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hashtag='#a2'");
```

Hope it helps